# How to present postgres schema dump in cleaner format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to dump my postgres schema in a more readable form. I am using pg_dump, so for the example below I run:

```
pg_dump -U user -p port -h host -s -t public.exchange_rates -d db_name > schema.sql
```

Instead of having output of the form

```
CREATE TABLE public.exchange_rates (
    currency_code character varying NOT NULL,
    xr_usd double precision NOT NULL,
    date_updated date,
    CONSTRAINT iso_4217_alpha CHECK ((char_length((currency_code)::text) = 3))
);


ALTER TABLE public.exchange_rates OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: COLUMN exchange_rates.xr_usd; Type: COMMENT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COMMENT ON COLUMN public.exchange_rates.xr_usd IS 'the number of USD you can buy for 1 unit of the currency';


--
-- Name: exchange_rates exchange_rates_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.exchange_rates
    ADD CONSTRAINT exchange_rates_pkey PRIMARY KEY (currency_code);
```

The output would be of the form

```
CREATE TABLE public.exchange_rates(
    currency_code VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    xr_usd double precision NOT NULL,
    date_updated DATE
)
```

I.e. contains the table information as you would if creating the table(s) from scratch or in a more human readable format

Comment: Do you realize that your desired output is not equivalent to the original (i.e. it is missing the `CONSTRAINT` clause), so it will not create the same table?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to add that in

Comment: The issue I'm having is when dumping a large number of tables, the results become unintelligible to others, and also can't be parsed by schema visualisation tools well.

Comment: So you basically want everything in the `CREATE TABLE` statement instead of multiple `ALTER TABLE` and `COMMENT` statements?

Comment: yes that'd be better.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution (which isn't quite what I want) would be something like

```
psql -U user -p port -h host -c "\d exchange_rates" > schema.txt
```

which does give a human readable display, but not in the CREATE TABLE style format